# Construct a self-dual basis of $\Bbb F_{16}$ over $\Bbb F_2$

Tags: finite-fields

Help please. I don't understand how to do that, but I want to solve this problem.
This problem is from "Introduction to finite fields and their applications" by Lidl and Niederreiter.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Try $F_4$ first. What does make a basis self dual?